# Add as Playlist - error looping through tracks

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to loop through a album which have x tracks, then add them to the playlist.

But I'm getting the follow error message in the console:

`Uncaught Error: link not allowed`

Code:

```
var album = models.Album.fromURI(uri);

$('.add-playlist').live('click', function() {
    var newPlaylist = new models.Playlist('Awesome album ' + album.name);
    $.each(album.data.tracks, function(i, track) {
        console.log(i + ' ::: ' + track.name);
        newPlaylist.add(track);
    });
});
```

It works if I add a single track to the playlist when I'm pressing the .add-playlist button but not when looping through the `album.data.tracks`array.

Probably something little I've missed. ;)

**Update:**
I got it working by removing the `.data.` from `album.data.tracks` so it says only `album.tracks`.